# Getting a random IBM MQ 2059 Error when connecting

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am using this code to connect to a queue manager. I am using the latest AMQMDNETSTD.dll version 9.2.3 for .Net Framework

```
Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
properties.Add( MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, Host );
properties.Add( MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, Port );
properties.Add( MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, ChannelName );
properties.Add( MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, TransportType );
properties.Add( MQC.CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, MQC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT);
properties.Add( MQC.SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY, "*SYSTEM");
properties.Add( MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256")
```

// Following line throws an exception randomly

```
MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager( qmName, properties );
```

At times randomly I will get a 2059 error when trying to connect. I had to put the connection within a try catch block and try to reconnect within the catch block. This is hacky way but it works.

Is there a way to keep trying to reconnect on failure or exception without doing this very bad code below?

```
try
{
MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager( qmName, properties );
}
catch(Exception)
{
MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager( qmName, properties );
}
```

EDIT: A little more context.

I am connecting to a queuemanager under a FQDN.
Under this Domain I have two servers (Server1 and Server 2) and each server can connect to any one of two queue managers called QM1 and QM2.

So if QM2 through server 1 is busy it should connect to QM1 on server 1 or server 2. It seems to be looking for the first QM on a single server and if it isn't available then it throws an exception.

Only then does it look for that QM again and works the second time.

Comment: Instead of host and port try the connection name list with a comma separated list of host(port). MQ with try them in order

Comment: Im a bit confused. So if my host is server1.com and my port is 1414, i would combine them into server1.com,1414 as the host and remove the properties.Add( MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, Port ); all together?

Comment: It is a different property, the format would be like this: `properties.Add(MQC.CONNECTION_NAME_PROPERTY,"server1.com(1414),server2.com(1414)");` see this page in the docs: [MQQueueManager.NET class](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=interfaces-mqqueuemanagernet-class)

Comment: Ok that does work but it defeats the purpose of using a FQDN and these servers as pools.  What if I have 20 servers? It would be a pain to type them all out like this. Is there a way to use just one FQDN that encompasses all of these servers?

Comment: Do you use a dns based load balancer like a F5 GTM?   MQ does offered reconnect logic but only of you are already successfully connected.   During connect time the only logic is to go through the connection name list or if you use a CCDT it will go through each matching entry.  If FQDN resolves to different servers you could repeat it a few times and MQ will try it that number of times.

Comment: Ok yea thats basically what im doing with the try catch. No we dont havea dns load balnacer5

Comment: How do you expect 1 FQDN to resolve to multiple servers.